# In Flutter how can i use if statment with user current lang

Tags: flutter, localization

i used this article
https://www.thirdrocktechkno.com/blog/how-to-implement-localization-in-flutter

to make my app multilang.
and i want to fit the banner in my app (no google ads) to the correct lang and correct on_tap

for example now i have just one:
            GestureDetector(
              child: Column(children: [
                Image(
                  image: AssetImage('assets/me.jpg'), // Here i want to use another image for each lang...
                ),
              ]),
              onTap: () {
                openUrl();
              },
            ),

I use flutter_localizations.

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experience with localization but you can try localizing the pathname.
For example

English pathname: `assets/me_en.jpg`

Spanish pathname: `assets/me_es.jp`

... and so on.